# BEST way prompt user 4 .txt, read it, separate by ",", iterate 2 find 1st str with "A" , "a", same 4 "Z" , "z" in C#?

Tags: c#

I have been at this problem all day long and seem like I am getting no-where fast. I am very very new at programming but do a good job understanding and explaining (I think so anyway). I have been at this computer for 12 hours trying to figure this out and I'm tired and brain needs a rest. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The part I cannot get past is figuring out how to make a decision based on the first char of each string. I have tried IndexOf with char, char[], strings, string[], mix mashin them and more than once, I have tried everything EXCEPT the RIGHT way. I tried StartsWith, Substring both attempting most likely every thing but how it is suppose to be done. Please help

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string files = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create string of all text in file
                string someText = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //Turn someText into a char arra
                char[] array = someText.ToCharArray();
                //Define vowels in a char array
                char[] vowels = { 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U' };
                //Converts someText to lowercase
                string lower = someText.ToLower();
                //Shows the lowercase text
                char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ',' };
                string[] split = 
                someText.Split(charSeparators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string result = split.ToString(); 
                int watch = result[0];
                int at = 0;
                int end = lower.Length;
                int start = 0;
                int count;
                while ((start <= end) && (at >= -1))
                {
                    // start+count must be a position within -str-.
                    count = start;
                    at = lower.IndexOf("a", start, count);
                    start = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("{0} ", at.ToString());
                                    
                    break;
                }   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message: {ex.Message}\n\n" +
                $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you spent a little more time describing the problem; that whole paragraph doesn't really tell us anything useful.

Comment: 1) You're searching on the text (i.e. `lower`), and not the separated commas array (i.e. `split`). 2) Your `while` loop is useless as it will only run a maximum of 1 time due to `break`. What I suggest  foryou do is use a `foreach` loop over split and use `Contains` to find the characters you want.

Comment: Even if the `break;` wasn't in the `while` loop, nothing in the loop will ever make the `while` condition `false`. Also, `IndexOf` will always return `-1` if `count` is `0` (and both `count` and `start` are always `0`)...

Comment: Told ya I was a freshie. Wow I messed up that many times!!! Its only my second program so. That last while loop was last thing I tried, I switched bits n pieces of it up so many times its....but thanks for all the posts, I will def read them , and Im gonna start from scratch cuz i got it all mixed up and non-sense every where

Comment: I got that loop from Microsoft, yes I tampered with it pretty heavily but still, it didnt work before I tampered

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: Also, please edit the title of your question. No everyone will understand all these '4's and '2's.

Comment: I tried to explain it properly but they limit how many words u use. Doing it the way I did was the only way, theres too much information and not enuf allowed space

Comment: You don't explain it in the title, you can do it in the body of the question. The title is a few words that summarize the question, like *"How to compare first character of a string"* (or whichever part you need help with)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

1. Prompt the user for a text file
2. Read the text file
3. Split the contents on the ',' character
4. Find the 1st string that starts with 'A' or 'a'
5. Find the first string that starts with 'Z' or 'z'

If so, here's one way to do it:

```
// Prompt the user for a text file
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Read the text file
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);

    // Split the contents on the ',' character
    string[] items = contents.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Create some variables to hold the first string that starts 
    // with 'A' and the first string that starts with 'Z'
    string firstAString = null;
    string firstZString = null;

    // Find the words and assign our variables
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        // If the 'a' string hasn't been assigned yet and this item starts with 'a'
        if (firstAString == null && 
            item.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            firstAString = item;
        }

        // If the 'z' string hasn't been assigned yet and this item starts with 'z'
        else if (firstZString == null && 
            item.StartsWith("Z", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            firstZString = item;
        }

        // If both our strings have been assigned a new value, we can exit the loop
        if (firstAString != null && firstZString != null) break;
    }

    // Do something with the strings here
}
```

Comment: Thank for the response, I dont want to just cheat and copy your code so I'm going to attempt to understand what u have going on there...might take an hour or two, but better than bein a cheat. Thanks man I appreciate it

Comment: Whats with declaring null values for stuff, would it still work without the null declaration?

Comment: StartsWith!!! haha hey I know that one, but sure dont know why I couldnt get it to work. Maybe cuz i didnt use &&.

Comment: I start them as `null` so that in the `foreach` loop I can tell if they've already been assigned or not by checking for `null`. Also it protects against the case where no matches are found in the `foreach` loop and I try to check them afterwards (variables cannot be used unless they've been assigned a value).

Comment: Until you can update the question with exactly what's "not working", I don't think anyone can help. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Loop to check dialog result 
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
//try&catch exception handler
try
//Block to try
{
//Create string of all text in file
string someText = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
//Converts someText to uppercase
string upper = someText.ToUpper();
//Shows the lowercase text
char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ',' };
string[] split = upper.Split(charSeparators,   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string b = "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z";
string[] A = b.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string c;
string d;
foreach (string a in split)
{
if (a.StartsWith(A[0]))
{
c = a;
MessageBox.Show(c);
}
if (a.StartsWith(A[25]))
{
d = a;
MessageBox.Show(d);
break;
}
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message: {ex.Message}\n\n" +
$"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
}
}
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Creating a string array representing the alphabet and then using a foreach to represent each individual string needing to compare as 'a', I was able to solve issue by using the index of the alphabet array as my compare option.